# Reading a binary file using C++

Tags: c++11, file-handling, binaryfiles

I am performing this simple task of writing into a binary file the contents of a class followed  by reading and displaying them. I achieve that using the follwing code:

```
class Matrix{   
    public:
    vector<vector<float>> Mat;
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix M, M1;   
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vector<float> row;
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            row.push_back(i+j);
        }
        M.Mat.push_back(row);
    }
    M.d=24;
    
    ofstream file("Data_for_Matrix2.bin", ios::binary|ios::trunc);
    if(!file.is_open()) cout<<"\nfile error!!";
    file.write((char*)&M, sizeof(M));
    file.close();
    
    ifstream file2("Data_for_Matrix2.bin", ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if(!file2.is_open()) cout<<"\nFile not open!";
    file2.seekg(0);
    file2.read((char*)&M1, sizeof(M1));
    cout<<"\nInteger data member: "<<M1.d;
    cout<<"\nMatrix data member: \n";
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            cout<<M1.Mat[i][j]<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the desired output. However, when I separately(using a differnt .cpp file) try to read the above created file using the code below, it doesn't work.

```
class Matrix{
    public:
    vector<vector<float>> Mat;
    int d;
};
int main()
{
    Matrix M1;  

    ifstream file2("Data_for_Matrix2.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
    if(!file2.is_open()) cout<<"\nFile not open!";
    file2.seekg(0);

    file2.read((char*)&M1, sizeof(M1));
    cout<<"\nInteger data member: "<<M1.d;
    cout<<"\nMatrix data member: \n";
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            cout<<M1.Mat[i][j]<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output it generates is,

*Integer data member: 24*

*Matrix data member:*

The process exits without printing the content of the matrix. I unable to identify the issue here. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving data members of `std::vector`. One of them is a pointer to the allocated storage. Then you read this pointer and attempt to dereference it to print matrix elements, which can not work. Matrix elements aren't even saved to a file.

To see why, imagine you had `struct Data { float* start; int count; }` and you store it for later like you do with `Matrix`. You don't store the elements. You store a pointer to where they are and their amount. But they won't be there forever, and even while they are, usually another process can't access them (in part due to security considerations).

Don't serialize `std::vector` like this. Store size and elements instead, and create a new container of required size when reading.

Alternatively, if dimensions of the matrix are always the same, you can replace `std::vector` with `std::array<std::array<float, 20>, 10>`, then all elements of a matrix will be stored "inside" `class Matrix` and your serialization will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! However, how does it successfully read in the first code? Also, I could not follow the changes you suggested. Can you be a bit more explicit. I don't have much experience in handling files.

Comment: What do you mean by serializing `std::vector`?

Comment: In the first code you read a pointer to an `std::vector`-allocated storage in the same process in which it was allocated. In this case it is a valid pointer, so you can (in practice) successfully use it. However, now you have two references to the same storage. Both references think they are unique, so each of them will try to deallocate that storage eventually, and deallocating the same pointer twice is very bad and should crash your program when M and M1 both get destroyed.

Comment: To be pedantic, I believe `file.write((char*)&M, sizeof(M));` invokes UB (undefined behaviour): you just can't treat a complicated object as a sequence of bytes. Similarly `file2.read((char*)&M1, sizeof(M1));`. For `std::array` it would be fine, because it is a POD or something. And once you have an UB in your code, you can't draw any conclusions from the results it produces, anything might happen.

Comment: @maxplus Avoid the phrase "should crash". A program with undefined behavior may crash, but some change in compiler optimizations or behavior could also make it work as expected, or give a wrong answer, or anything else, and "undefined behavior" allows all those results. So we don't want to rely on those crashes when debugging or evaluating what would happen given bad code.

Comment: "a POD or something" - the technical term here is "trivially copyable type" (which `std::vector<T>` is not).

Comment: @ascepler, I believe that's what I said in my following comment, "anything might happen". Should != must. I merely conveyed an intuitive notion that crash is a likely outcome, but not guaranteed. Such a notion is useful, e.g. for debugging a big project. Knowing what to expect "on average" can help find a bug quicker -- as long as that expectation is not taken to be an absolute guarantee.

Comment: Are you sure "POD" is not a technical term in C++11?

Comment: @maxplus POD type (before C++20) is a more restricted subset of trivially copyable type. The trivial copy is all we really need to deal with an object as a sequence of bytes, if we can assume a constant ABI. (And if we don't, none of the C++ type descriptions let us do this - even for `int` and so on we need to worry about at least byte order.)

Comment: @maxplus I understood a bit. Are you impying that there are two problems here? First being the way I am treating my (complicated) object while passing to `write()`. Second, while reading, that fact that I read the pointer to `std::vector` and attempt to dereference it. If so, can you explain why the second one is a problem? You also, in your answer, add that the matrix elements are not being saved to the file at all. Is that a  consequence of the first problem?

Comment: @SourinDey, Yes, two problems. No, I would say it's a consequence of the second (but the pedantic, IMO less helpful answer is that the first is enough to not reason any further). I've expanded the answer. If you have further questions about pointers, they should go in a separate question (or even better, read up, I'm sure it's not hard to find a good tutorial).